# exe file deployed by pyinstaller can not run on another pc(virtual machine)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyqt5

develop machine：

- windows7 64bit
- python2.7.13 32bit
- Qt5.7.1 32bit vs2015 + PyQt5_gpl-5.7.1
- pyinstaller ,pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip

I deployed using `pyinstaller qrprint.py`,it works well on this machine.

Then i copyed folder to virtual machine(vmware workstation + winowd7 32bit) and run, it doesn't work with infomation `Failed to execute script pyi_rth_qt5`

I try to search solution，like https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1679, it can not help.
I used `DependencyWalker` found the missing dll, it can not work.

This is the infomation on two machine with `pyinstaller qrprint.py --debug`

devolop:

```
PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
LOADER: executable is C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python demo\dist\qrPrint\qrPrint.exe
LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python demo\dist\qrPrint
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python demo\dist\qrPrint\qrPrint.exe
LOADER: No need to extract files to run; setting extractionpath to homepath
LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python demo\dist\qrPrint)
LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
LOADER: Python library: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python demo\dist\qrPrint\python27.dll
LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
LOADER: sys.prefix is C:\Users\ADMINI~1\Desktop\PYTHON~1\dist\qrPrint
LOADER: Setting runtime options
LOADER: Initializing python
LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
LOADER: Post-init sys.path is C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python demo\dist\qrPrint
LOADER: Setting sys.argv
LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
LOADER: extracted struct
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod02_archive
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod03_importers
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
LOADER: PYZ archive: out00-PYZ.pyz
LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
LOADER: Running pyi_rth__tkinter.py
LOADER: Running pyi_rth_qt5.py
LOADER: Running pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py
LOADER: Running qrPrint.py
```

virtual machine:

```
PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
LOADER: executable is C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\qrPrint\qrPrint.exe
LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\qrPrint
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\qrPrint\qrPrint.exe
LOADER: No need to extract files to run; setting extractionpath to homepath
LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\qrPrint)
LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
LOADER: Python library: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\qrPrint\python27.dll
LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
LOADER: sys.prefix is C:\Users\ADMINI~1\Desktop\qrPrint
LOADER: Setting runtime options
LOADER: Initializing python
LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
LOADER: Post-init sys.path is C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\qrPrint
LOADER: Setting sys.argv
LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
LOADER: extracted struct
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod02_archive
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod03_importers
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
LOADER: PYZ archive: out00-PYZ.pyz
LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
LOADER: Running pyi_rth__tkinter.py
LOADER: Running pyi_rth_qt5.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt5.py", line 56, in <m
odule>
  File "c:\dvlp\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers
.py", line 546, in load_module
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。
Failed to execute script pyi_rth_qt5
LOADER: OK.
LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
```

what should I do?

Comment: I guess you need QT to be installed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I found the reason, it's so stupid. thanks for your suggestion

Comment: `找不到指定的模块。` means "The specified module could not be found" if anyone is curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason. it's so stupid that I forgot to install vc runtime libiray.
When installed，it works well.

But i can not work on XP, I think the reason is Qt5.7.1 msvc 2015 not support XP.

How to complie PyQt5 from Qt5.7.1 with supporting XP is an other question.